# Named Lazy import in React Workaround

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I made a workaround for named Lazy imports in React I want someone to check if this is actually working as lazy import or not.

**Toast.js**

```js
import { ToastContainer } from "react-toastify";
export default ToastContainer;
```

**App.js**

```js
const ToastContainer = React.lazy(() => import("../main/shared/toast"));

return(
      <Suspense fallback={null}>
        <ToastContainer />
      </Suspense>
);
```

Comment: take a look at the network panel, it will request for new chunk if everything works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As React official documentation said "currently only supports default exports. If the module you want to import uses named exports, you can create an intermediate module that reexports it as the default. This ensures that tree shaking keeps working and that you don’t pull in unused components."

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html

It is working as a lazy component you export this as a default component in 2nd line

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer, and the documentation that it refers to, are slightly misleading.

`lazy()` expects a *thenable* function, meaning that you can load your module and then select which named export you want to import. Using your example, that would become:

```
React.lazy(async () => {
  return {
    default: (import("../main/shared/toast")).ToastContainer
  }
})
```